# Does time delay in a sequential logic circuit block have a influence on synthesize or place or route's result？

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

I use Xilinx ISE as a IDE.
If I add a 100 ps delay at every assignment in a always(Verilog)/process(VHDL) with sensitive list only have clock and reset.
Like this.

```
always@(posedge clk)
    if(rst)
      a <= #100 'd0;
    else
      a <= #100 b;
    end
```

I think the delay function is only effect the simulation process.Because every book and user guide tell us `delay` is not synthesizable.

But I still wondering if the delay function can really effect the place or route's result?Like static timing or clock report?
Like can make a circuit max frequency higher or slower?

Comment: [This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121121/why-delays-cannot-be-synthesized-in-verilog) might be interesting topic for you.

Comment: It almost the same question.But nobody have a authority evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there's nothing intrinsic about delay statements that makes them unsynthesizable, however it's wildly impractical to attempt to do so.  The reason for this is that once on the FPGA you are dealing with a physical circuit whose performance varies with PVT (process, voltage, temperature) and can do so by a lot!  The only hedge against this would be an analog circuit that attempts to sense all of the above and adjust itself accordingly.  Such a beast will still be limited in what it can do, and would be physically large and power hungry depending on the rage of delay and the variance in all of the above you want to support.

So with than in mind and considering that there is very little (read: no) demand for this outside of special purpose IO FPGA vendors don't provide any such components making the construct unsythesizable.

Answer (score 3):

No the #delay in your code is not going to affect the timing of the design when it is loaded on to the FPGA.

It also does not affect the place and route results or the static timing analysis. Both of these steps use timing information that is provided by the manufacturer in the form of device models.

Comment: Do you have a authority evidence?

Comment: #delays are simulation-only artifacts and are dropped during synthesis of any kind (hopefully with error or warning messages). So, check your fpga build logs. It should give you the evidence. Saying that some `emulation` platforms have special hardware to emulate some of the test bench code including delays, using the fastest emulation clock for the latter. However simple fpga hardware most likely has it not. In any case it requires special compilation for the affected blocks.

Comment: @LiangHe as AlperKucukkomurler has pointed out, the Xilinx Design guide talks about this. Additionally, you could obtain the evidence yourself. The synthesis of the simple FF example in either Vivado or Quartus would show you that irrespective of what delay value you include, the STA results are alway the same. You could also create a *LED blinky" design and measure how fast your LED blinks for different values in the #delay directive. Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you.@Serge But I have try in ISE 14.5 and no related warning or error.

Comment: Thank you.@Prashant I will try to check the STA results.

Comment: I don't means the function result only. Like blink faster or slower.I think it will not happen.I mean can `delay` influence the place and route result? Like make a circuit's max frequency higher or lower.@Prashant

Answer (score 1):

Delay statements (`#100`) are usually ignored during synthesis in Verilog. So in synthesis it is the same as:

```
always@(posedge clk)
    if(rst)
      a <= 0;
    else
      a <= b;
    end
```

Xlinx [Synthesis and Simuation Design Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/sim.pdf) states:

> Delays in Synthesis Code
>
> Do not use Wait for XX ns (VHDL) or the #XX (Verilog) statements in
>   your code.  (...) This statement does not synthesize to a component.
>   In designs that include this construct, the functionality of the
>   simulated design does not always match the functionality of the
>   synthesized design.
>
> (...)
>
> Wait for XX ns Statement Verilog Coding Example
>
> `#XX;`
>
> Do not use the After XX ns statement in your VHDL code or the Delay
>   assignment in your Verilog code
>
> (...)
>
> Delay Assignment Verilog Coding Example
>
> `assign #XX Q=0;`
>
> XX specifies the number of nanoseconds that must pass before a
>   condition is executed. This statement is usually ignored by the
>   synthesis tool. In this case, the functionality of the simulated
>   design does not match the functionality of the synthesized design.

Comment: Do you have a authority evidence?

Comment: @LiangHe I added the quote from Xilinx user guide, to the answer.

Comment: @AlperKucukkomurler I have never seen the #delay actually affect my synthesized design, but isn't it strange, that even the Xilinx Synthesis and Simulation Design guide should say "the delay condition is *usually* ignored by the synthesis tool" when they themselves are the synthesis tool. Isn't it expected that they would know what their synthesis tool is doing?

Comment: Yes.Like they don't know how their tool wroks.@Prashant

Answer (score 0):

"Usually" there is no impact on synthesis and P&R results.

> Xilinx: This statement is **usually** ignored by the synthesis tool.

When does it have impact then?

Although the delay statement is ignored by the synthesis tool, the HDL code is a little bit different. That may change the seed of randomization in any stage (parsing, elaboration, synthesis etc.), so there is a possibility for different results. These results may be better or worse.

If a delay statement exists in the code, the following warning is expected from Xilinx ISE:

> WARNING:Xst:916 - design.v line x: Delay is ignored for synthesis.

Comment: Thank you.I have checked it on Xilinx ISE 14.5 with VHDL 200X but no such warning has been found. @ahmedus

Comment: From IEEE Std 1076.6-1999 8.8.1 Wait statement. 8.8.4 signal assignment to Vivado's UG901 VHDL Constructs Support Status Table 5-10 Wait Statement Wait for time_expression **Unsupported**, Signal Assignment Statement Delay is **ignored** a time expression has always been ignored while in a process a wait statement not including timeout clauses may be used (e.g. 1076.6-2004 6.1.3.2 Edge-sensitive storage using a single wait statement).  Your documentation does not lead you astray. How could an ignored expression affect mapped constructs or their characteristics?

Comment: @user1155120 I know it sounds weird, but sometimes even comments (in source files) change the result.

Comment: time expressions can't be mistaken for pragmas.